# Firebase instance ID, get token for many different authorized entities throws INVALID_SENDER

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have no clue what I am doing wrong, the following code works well

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("12", "FCM");
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("11", "FCM");
```

but another one

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("8", "FCM")
```

throws an IOException about INVALID_SENDER

All from stack trace

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzo.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzo.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzr.then(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The code itself runs in Runnable Thread instance

Comment: [Sender ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) should be the value shown in the Cloud Messaging tab of your project setting.

Comment: I already know it (read it somewhere on SO), but that does not make it clear why I can use sender IDs other than mine.

Comment: Could you post the actual source code? Are all these lines in one handler/runnable thread? Or is the 3rd one called later on in your app?

Comment: There are cases when a single app would want to register with multiple senders for notifications. Think a news app with multiple sources, each source has their own sender ID allowing the app to register for notifications from each source.

Comment: Arthur actually answered my question, but I can't close the question as it's formed as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This means exactly what it says: **Invalid Sender ID**.
You should obtain your SENDER_ID from FCM Developers project console in the "Cloud Messaging" tab. This intended to obtain registration tokens within one project for several registered apps.

[image]